# UI lag when addPeriodicTimeObserver to AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, avplayer, lag

I have a UI like Youtube (Video player above and a list of videos below in a tableView).

When I add the time observer, the tableView below freezes for a few second.

```
observer = self.avPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMake(1, 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (time) in

    let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time)
    let duration = self.avPlayer.currentItem?.asset.duration.seconds

    print(seconds, duration)

})
```

I think the problem is with the `queue: DispatchQueue.main` but I do not know how to fix it.

**Note**: When I remove the observer, I do not have freezing problems.

Comment: Why don't you use global queue or background queue instead of main? What you need to do is just replacing `DispatchQueue.main` to `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)`

Comment: Please try by passing `nil` instead of `DispatchQueue.main`. If you pass `NULL`, the main queue (obtained using `dispatch_get_main_queue()`) will be used. Passing a concurrent queue to this method will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you guys, `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)` works for me.